# Understanding (symbolized) iOS crash log

Tags: ipad, crash, ios, logging

This is a continuation to my previous attempt to resolve a pesky issue affecting a few instances of my app.
The problem happens on a few iPads only, but as you know, these are the ones who take their time to leave a nice, thoughtful review :-/

Anywho, I finally got the crash log symbolized properly, and it is pointing to:

```
NonogramsAppDelegate.m:105
```

The line it points to is the last line of the function:

```
return YES;
```

I am not sure what to make of it, again, any help from you awesome people would be greatly appreciated, by me and the poor souls who tried my app once, got addicted, and now it crashes on launch...

I pasted the entire **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in the previous post here:
[iPad app works on most devices, gets EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) on some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609084/ipad-app-works-on-most-devices-gets-exc-crash-sigabrt-on-some)

Below is more of the log.

**THANKS!!**

```
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00042f12 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x000046a4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                 0x00094174 -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 108
11  CoreFoundation                 0x00093afa ___forwarding___ + 482
12  CoreFoundation                 0x000306c8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  iPadNonograms                  0x000034f8 -[NonogramsAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (NonogramsAppDelegate.m:105)
14  UIKit                          0x00003e58 -[UIApplication _performInitializationWithURL:payload:] + 336
15  UIKit                          0x00003b22 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:] + 394
16  UIKit                          0x0004f8c4 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1336
17  UIKit                          0x0004f242 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is *the* problem, but this:

```
NSNumber *pref_gameInProgress_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; 
NSNumber *pref_soundOn_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]; 
NSNumber *pref_buttonsOnLeft_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; 
NSNumber *pref_gameNumber_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pref_currentPuzzleId]; 
NSNumber *pref_gameSize_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pref_gameSize]; 
NSNumber *pref_gameTimer_temp = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pref_gameTimerValue]; 

// ...

[pref_gameInProgress_temp release]; 
[pref_gameSize_temp release]; 
[pref_soundOn_temp release]; 
[pref_gameTimer_temp release]; 
[pref_gameNumber_temp release]; 
[pref_buttonsOnLeft_temp release];
```

is a little weird. You're releasing a series of autoreleased instances. Those releases look rather unnecessary if not a little dangerous.

Comment: Just took them out!
Build and Analyze pointed them out, so I removed the. Rookie mistake - thanks for the answer!
Hanaan